# ¿Cómo dar valor a una calificación de estrellas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo esta función que crea una calificación de estrellas, pero quiero hacer una función que tenga como parámetro un número entero del 1 al 5 y devuelva una calificación de estrellas con la misma cantidad de estrellas pintadas que el parámetro que le he pasado por entrada .

¿Puede alguien ayudarme?

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState(0) // initial rating value

function MyComponent(){
      // Catch Rating value
      const handleRating = (rate: number) => {
        setRating(rate)
        // other logic
      }
    
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <Rating onClick={handleRating} ratingValue={rating} /* Available Props */ />
        </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: Si ya hiciste la función para crear calificaciones ¿Qué es lo que te impide hacer la otra función? O ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿O la función es robada?

Comment: El problema esta que al usar hooks no me deja meter como parametro un integer de numero para que se vaya pintando las estrellas de valoraciones

Answer (score 1):

Por ejemplo, algo básico con Material UI podría ser así:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Star';
import StarOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/StarOutline';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Rating value={5} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Rating = (props) => {
  const { value } = props;

  const ratingArr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1].fill(0, value);

  return (
      <div className="Rating">
        {ratingArr.map((rating) => (rating ? <StarIcon /> : <StarOutlineIcon />))}
      </div>
  );
};
```